# how get a django ajax post user

Tags: ajax, django, json, angularjs

i am designing a blog using django 1.5 .
for the comment function,i am planning use ajax post json data to server.
in my blog only registered user can post comment,that means all users are logged in

i use angularjs 1.2 $http in page to post ajax data

as i do not know much about json  .in the json data ,i only post the comment data ,not include other user info .my question is ,can i get the user object use this code

```
user = User.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

in this way ,i will know who post this comment.
if it can not ,how can i  fetch the user object in django .
in other place i see people use this way

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ user.id }}" />
```

and post the user.id with ajax.
i do not think that is a good way .

any one knows a better solution

Answer (score 2):

`request.user` is already a `User` object. You can use it directly. If you need just the id use `request.user.pk`.

I agree that using user id received from a browser is not a good idea indeed - this information can be easily spoofed. `request.user` is the right source of information about the current user.

Comment: that is to say.no matter ajax json or normal way to post data.i can always use (request.user) to get the user object in case the user already loggin in ?

Answer (score 1):

Exposing the user id in a html template is not an good idea.
Anyway, the ajax call should also send the session cookie in the request. So the django authentication/session framework should handle authenticationn things transparently for you (assuming you are using the build in session and authentication modules). Like Ludwik also stated, just access `request.user` on your serverside and you should be good.

Comment: thanks .now i know how to deal with json .i thought json is pure data ,it not include any other info,that is why i ask this post here .